# php mapping keys to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

Quite new to php. I would be grateful is anyone can provide guidance about mapping the values in this array using php this is the output from var_dump

```
array(3) {
  ["k"]=>
  string(78) "method,from_tag,to_tag,callid,sip_code,sip_reason,time,from_user,to_user,token"
  ["v"]=>
  string(326) "BYE,gFNk8BZBg,B2B.269.327,KjmE8oPOV1,200,OK,Wed May 28 23:11:43 2014
,patientdemo1.gmail,sip:join.me@192.168.1.20:5060;transport=udp,037d30d7239a0a16a658474822c3c9acf7995ac781a9c1c8b4b1a7361f24400d71216209c18eff8b8b0400bb55890bb2a78eb3064b603e6ac4e270b76c36be0e365bf096e426cfb6621aac13fdec54e7bbce74b3d63244b4cb622b16e27da1c4"
  ["query_type"]=>
  string(6) "insert"
}
```

as you may have noticed the column keys are within first array with key "k" and the values are under "v"

I need to pull some of these values out by referencing the keys within "k"

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do this at all?  Can you show your code? Or are you just expecting someone to write this code for you? Other questions - why are you dealing with this input format to begin with? Hos do you handle cases with commas in the values themselves?

Comment: [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment. You'd use [**`explode()`**](http://www.php.net/explode) to set your `keys` and `values` into their arrays respectively.

Done so as below:

```
<?php

$things = array(
'k' => 'method,from_tag,to_tag,callid,sip_code,sip_reason,time,from_user,to_user,token',
'v' => 'BYE,gFNk8BZBg,B2B.269.327,KjmE8oPOV1,200,OK,Wed May 28 23:11:43 2014
,patientdemo1.gmail,sip:join.me@192.168.1.20:5060;transport=udp,037d30d7239a0a16a658474822c3c9acf7995ac781a9c1c8b4b1a7361f24400d71216209c18eff8b8b0400bb55890bb2a78eb3064b603e6ac4e270b76c36be0e365bf096e426cfb6621aac13fdec54e7bbce74b3d63244b4cb622b16e27da1c4'
);

$keys = explode(',', $things['k']);
$values = explode(',', $things['v']);

?>
```

### Which returns:

**Keys**

```
Array
(
    [0] => method
    [1] => from_tag
    [2] => to_tag
    [3] => callid
    [4] => sip_code
    [5] => sip_reason
    [6] => time
    [7] => from_user
    [8] => to_user
    [9] => token
)
```

**Values**

```
Array
(
    [0] => BYE
    [1] => gFNk8BZBg
    [2] => B2B.269.327
    [3] => KjmE8oPOV1
    [4] => 200
    [5] => OK
    [6] => Wed May 28 23:11:43 2014

    [7] => patientdemo1.gmail
    [8] => sip:join.me@192.168.1.20:5060;transport=udp
    [9] => 037d30d7239a0a16a658474822c3c9acf7995ac781a9c1c8b4b1a7361f24400d71216209c18eff8b8b0400bb55890bb2a78eb3064b603e6ac4e270b76c36be0e365bf096e426cfb6621aac13fdec54e7bbce74b3d63244b4cb622b16e27da1c4
)
```

And now you just need to loop through the values like so using `foreach()`:

```
$data = array();
foreach($keys as $i => $key) {
    $data[$key] = $values[$i];
}
```

Which would product your final output of:

```
Array
(
    [method] => BYE
    [from_tag] => gFNk8BZBg
    [to_tag] => B2B.269.327
    [callid] => KjmE8oPOV1
    [sip_code] => 200
    [sip_reason] => OK
    [time] => Wed May 28 23:11:43 2014

    [from_user] => patientdemo1.gmail
    [to_user] => sip:join.me@192.168.1.20:5060;transport=udp
    [token] => 037d30d7239a0a16a658474822c3c9acf7995ac781a9c1c8b4b1a7361f24400d71216209c18eff8b8b0400bb55890bb2a78eb3064b603e6ac4e270b76c36be0e365bf096e426cfb6621aac13fdec54e7bbce74b3d63244b4cb622b16e27da1c4
)
```

### Working Example

---

#### Footnotes

This probably isn't the most efficient way to handle/do what you want to do. You should rethink how the first array with the columns/values is created and restructure that to suit your needs.

You ***should*** use [**`array_combine()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) instead! 

*If this answers your question, just click on the arrow to the left there until it is green :) to mark this question as answered!*

Comment: Instead of using a `foreach` loop to generate the final array, you could just use `array_combine`. (Or rather _should_ then _could_, because native functions always perform better then writing your own loops, although this might not be that relevant in this case. But it makes for shorter and cleaner code as well.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much for that! I knew there was a native function, just couldn't think of the name! :)